# Cannot create a new virtual manager using virt-manager on ubuntu 14.04.5 with armv7l on qemu

Tags: 14.04, qemu

Unable to complete install: `internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Error: Cirrus VGA not available`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 96, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1983, in do_install
    guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1246, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1314, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3202, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Error: Cirrus VGA not available
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316115/qemu-arm7l-virt-manager-qemu-missing-securedigital-device-error-cirrus

Comment: This issue was raised by someone before in the following link and I am not sure if it is fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316115/qemu-arm7l-virt-manager-qemu-missing-securedigital-device-error-cirrus